# Proofreading Browser Plugin

Tags: plugins, browser, edit

As part of our site deployment process we typically have proofreaders go through content on site at various stages in the process.  For editing that happens before it gets to the site there are plenty of tools for tracking edits, but once the content is up on the site, we do not have a good method for this.  I was thinking there might be a plugin or program that would allow our editors to load the site and mark-up the content in page as they would a tracked changes word document.

It seems like the kind of thing that aught to exist, but so far I have not found any god options for Chrome or Firefox. Has anyone made use of a tool like this in the past that they might recommend.